# Using go test - Is it possible to run tests for a single package WITHOUT the relative path to the package?

Tags: unit-testing, go

Using `go test` - is there a way to run tests for a package inside the current project without providing the relative path?

I can run `go test fmt` for example regardless of my current working directory and `go` will look around for the `fmt` package and will start running its tests. This is `go test` in package list mode.

However, I can’t figure out how to run `go test` for a package in my current project.

**For example** - given this folder structure:

```
mySpecialProject
|--foo
|--bar
   |--bizz
   |--buzz
```

I already know that I can run `go test ./bar/bizz` to run the tests in the `bizz` package; I know about using `go test -run` to run specifically named tests; I also know about `go test ./...` to run all tests for all packages inside the current directory. That's not what I'm asking for here. I'm looking to run tests *from the root of a project* for a single package without providing the relative path.

Reading [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go/internal/test) about `go test` regarding package list mode, it "feels" like it should work to run `go test bizz` or something like it to run the tests in bizz without providing the relative path.

When I run that command however, it just says `package bizz is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.1/libexec/src/bizz)`

Any ideas? I've figured out a workaround (`find . -type d -name "bizz" | xargs go test`) but I'd much rather use something built into go test.

Comment: `fmt` is part of the standard library, so is at the "root" of the package namespace. That's why it works that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to execute `go test ./**/bizz`. This is a shell feature called globstar, so depending on your shell this might work for you. You may need to enable first with `set -o globstar` or `shopt -o globstar`.

Edit:
`go test ./.../bizz` also works, in this case it is a go feature. Only difference is that this command doesn't work of bizz is a direct sub-directory of the current working dir.

Comment: `go test ./.../bizz` works exactly as I had hoped! I don't follow your caveat though. When will this command not work?

Comment: When i tested it it didn't trigger on ./bizz but did on ./bar/bizz like it always expects it to be at least 2 directories deep. Anyway, happy this was what you were looking for

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain this is not possible. `go test` calls [PackagesAndErrors](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/e0e6e4d23fe840c2c9b4caed30930cad6788b797/src/cmd/go/internal/load/pkg.go#L2622) function to process the args.

Stepping through the code i don't see any way for what you want to work natively to `go test`.  The shell trickery you are using seems to be the best way to do what you are wanting.

As there might be another way around your issue, can you describe why you are wanting this specific behavior?

Comment: To be honest - it is a bit of a hacky thing I'm doing as a temporary solution in preparation for a demo :O 
I will be given a list of packages and am trying to write a bash script that will go to the root of a project and will run the integration tests if they exist in the project.
Here's my working code with @caveman's answer:
Assuming $DEPS is a space-delimited list of packages:
`echo $DEPS | xargs -n 1 -I{} gotest -v -tags=integration ./.../{})`